# "in pretence" and "lordship"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> There was no doubt that a man, in succeeding to a ***lordship*** in
>   right of his wife, would wish to bear the arms associated therewith.
>   He placed them, therefore, upon his own, and arms exclusively of a
>   territorial character have certainly very frequently been placed ***in
>   pretence***. His own arms he would look upon as arms of descent ; they
>   consequently occupied the field of his shield. The ***lordship*** of
>   his wife he did not enjoy through descent, and consequently he would
>   naturally incline to place it ***in pretence***. (Fox-Davies, Arthur
>   Charles., A Complete Guide to Heraldry, p539)

1. I do know what is the conception of "in pretence" in heraldry exactly, but what is I can not perceive is the exact meaning of the term in English; does it mean "to claim" or "to pretend" or something else?
2. Which one is the meaning of "lordship" in above paragraph: "the rank or dignity of a lord" or "the authority or power of a lord" or "the domain or territory belonging to or under the jurisdiction of a lord"?

Comment: Pretence: [claim](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/escutcheon-of-pretence); lordship: [the authority or state of being a lord](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/lordship)

Comment: "...in feudal days arms were often associated with lordships, and schemes of quarterings usually illustrated inheritance of property rather than blood..." (Brooke-Little, J. P.., An Heraldic Alphabet, p172) Is "lordship" here same as above?

Comment: Yes: "the state of being a lord".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To *pretend to* something means to maintain a claim to it. In colloquial discourse it is practically never used of any but false claims, but in formal discourse the term is indifferent to the legitimacy of the claim.

Heraldry is concerned only with “the rank or dignity of a lord”; what power or territorial authority accompanies a particular title is a matter of law (and politics).

Consequently, an armiger who wishes to maintain a claim to a dignity he does not hold by right of descent, or to a territorial authority which may or may not accompany a territorial title, places the arms of the dignity or territory “in pretence” with his own arms.

Comment: I really confused about "lordship", could please guide me why Fox-Davies writes: "...and arms exclusively of a territorial character..." while, as you said, heraldry is concerned only with “the rank or dignity of a lord”? In other hand, Oerkelens says that he is sure lordship does not refer to the person or the general authority...

Comment: @user64617 Suppose you are created "Earl of Wessex" - does that entitle you to bear the arms of that county? Maybe - so you post the territorial arms in pretence.

Answer (score 1):

1. Since this is a very specific heraldic term, I doubt any modern uses of "pretence" will help much. But looking at the words itself the verb [pretend](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=pretend&searchmode=none) means "to profess, to assert", in French "to lay claim". So placing the wife's arms in the centre of the shield indicated an acquired claim as opposed to a title or property that was inherited.
2. In this case I am sure *lordship* does not refer to the person or the general authority, but specifically the domain or territory. Of course, the authority that comes with the territory is assumed, but if one is a duke already, acquiring an earldom through marriage would increase possession more than power.

Comment: I mixed up tenere and tendere, I edited my answer :)

Comment: OK. Downvote reversed!